# Replace a number with text from a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to pull account reports out of a system but the regions are represented as a number. I have a separate list that has two columns, one with the region name and one with the corresponding number. I'm looking to write a formula that identifies the number in the report column and populates it with the region name from my static table.

Example:

**Region List**
          **A1**           **B1**
**1**       00              London
**2**      01              West Midlands
**3**      02              Greater Manchester

**Report**
             **A2**                    **B2** 
 
**1**     Customer A        00  
 
**2**     Customer B        02
**3**     Customer C        02
**4**     Customer D        01
**5**     Customer E        00

As mentioned, I want to populate column B2 with the data from B1. B2's numbers will corrispond with A1's numbers. It's worth mentioning that there are also some variations like 07D or 19H, so the formula would need to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function, I hope it will work.

```
=INDEX('Region List'!$B$1:$B$3;MATCH($B1;'Region List'!$A$1:$A$3;0))
```